# Mule esb integration with Mule MQ

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have gone through the documentation of how we can integrate mule esb with mule mq. But i couldn't find any download link for mule MQ. Even i read on mule blog the mule mq is out of market now. Can anybody comment on this. 
below are the ref links

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/MULE2USER/MuleMQ+Integration
http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/where_to_get_mule_mq_software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MuleSoft has completely abandoned MuleMQ. Use another message broker, like HornetQ, ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 1):

Mule MQ is now totally deprecated.But it provides a seamless integration between various MOM which utilized JMS and other tools.

By default, Mule provides a JMS endpoint that can be used to send and receive messages using JMS API.

We can prefer the queuing vendors based upon two need
**1.AMQP**

Advanced Message Queuing Protocol,which provides so many advanced features in  queue to provide the routing needs.RabbitMQ,ActiveMQ etc..

**2.MSMQ**

MSMQ is MOM provided by Microsoft as a component.If required it can be enabled from **Turn Windows Features On or Off**.It doesn't implements much features that AMQP provide.It also doesn't have a topic feature which is available in MSMQ.

I hope this answer helps you.
Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

As of now Mule MQ is discontinued, You can user other third party Queue broker solutions like - [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html), [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/download.html).